# How to update object with relation to list of objects via thymeleaf form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am in trouble :/ I have one object that has a list of another objects and I want to change this list via select box and inputs, but when I submit this, the list is empty

Here is my code (model, thymelaf form, controller):

```
public class BetConfigVM {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<BetPriorityVM> betPriorities;

    ....getters and setters
}


public class BetPriorityVM {

    private long id;
    private CourseType courseType;
    private BigDecimal minCourse;
    private BigDecimal maxCourse;

    ....getters and setters
}


<form action="#" th:action="@{/betConfigSaveOrUpdate}" th:object="${config}" method="post">            
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
    <span th:field="*{betPriorities}" th:each="prio : *{betPriorities}">
         <select>
            <option th:each="type : ${T(com.model.database.CourseType).values()}"
                    th:value="${type}" th:text="${type}" th:selected="${prio.courseType == type}">
            </option>
         </select>
         <input type="text" th:field="${prio.minCourse}" />
         <input type="text" th:field="${prio.maxCourse}" />
     </span>
     <input type="submit" th:value="Save" name="action"/>
 </form>


 @RequestMapping(value = "/betConfigSaveOrUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveOrUpdateUser(@ModelAttribute("config") BetConfigVM configVM, @RequestParam String action,  Model model) {
        System.out.println(configVM.getName());
        System.out.println("Size " + configVM.getBetPriorities().size());
        model.addAttribute("config", configVM);

        return "user/betConfigEdit";
    }
```

Do you have any idea how to pass the changed list in the object?

EDIT:
Adding controller part that will show the form:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/changeBetConfig", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String changeBetConfig(Model model, @RequestParam("id") long id) {
        BetConfig betConfig = betConfigRepository.findById(id);
        BetConfigVM configVM = new BetConfigVM(betConfig);
        model.addAttribute("config", configVM);
        return "user/betConfigEdit";
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a `@GetMapping` where you add the `config` bean to the model?

Comment: Hi, I edited my question and added part of controller that will add bean config to model.

Comment: If you do `configVM.getId()` in your post method, does a value print?  (You can also step through with a debugger.)  Also, no exceptions, right?

Comment: No it doesn't because I don't handle id value in the form, but I've edited my question with the body of this method. I'm logging the name and it is work, but size of the list is 0. So list is not handled via the form, after that I want to show the same page and I can see that there are no values in the list now.

Comment: I'm thinking that your select tag needs to be bound directly to thymeleaf and not nested in a `span` tag.  Like: `select th:field="*{betPriorities}"`.  That's usually what it looks like in the docs.

Comment: But if I tag the select how it will be handled? Because betPriorities are objects with three params and I need to edit all these params, the first one will be edited by select box and the next will be modified by inputs so I need to somehow iterate over list and for this list create select box and two input box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution..the form has to look like this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/betConfigSaveOrUpdate}" th:object="${config}" method="post">            
<input type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
<span th:each="prio, rowStat  : *{betPriorities}">
     <select th:field="*{betPriorities[__${rowStat.index}__].courseType>
        <option th:each="type : ${T(com.model.database.CourseType).values()}"
                th:value="${type}" th:text="${type}" th:selected="${prio.courseType == type}">
        </option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" th:field="*{betPriorities[__${rowStat.index}__].minCourse}" />
     <input type="text" th:field="*{betPriorities[__${rowStat.index}__].maxCourse}" />
 </span>
 <input type="submit" th:value="Save" name="action"/>
```